# Convert data structure (list of list) to Html table

Tags: java, html

i have many 2d arrays and i want to display them in HTMLTable (dynamically).
is there any tool or library to make it

Comment: just loop through them and create the html code for it..

Comment: that's what i found it easier to keep searching

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this, Jquery javascript library, You can create dynamic HTML element using this.

https://jquery.com/

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_dom_add.asp